# How to extract all tracks from a DVD movie

Tags: audio, video, dvd, extract, multiplexing

I have a DVD movie that contains special features. I'd like to extract everything from the DVD in question as individual items - the special features in particular, but also audio tracks, subtitle tracks, chapters and the like.

Pretty much anything that can be extracted, I'd like to extract, and I'd like to be able to do so without prior knowledge of which tracks exist in the container and where, which is why tools like FFmpeg would be unsuitable in this instance. My primary reason for doing so is to transcode and/or remux these individual elements as needed.

How can do I this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but is an involved process that requires several different applications, as there's currently no one piece of software that will extract *all* of the content from a DVD.

#### 1. Use [MakeMKV](https://www.makemkv.com/) to extract all video titles from the DVD

Despite what its homepage says, MakeMKV is not a transcoder, but a DVD ripper - it decrypts and then rips content directly from its DVD container into an .MKV container, *without* any re-encoding of the video in question. This means that the extracted content suffers from none of the loss in quality that it would if it was being re-encoded.

Click `Open Disc` to select your source DVD disc or .ISO image:

[image]

MakeMKV will extract all video elements from the DVD (technically known as titles) and output each one as an individual .MKV file.

These include everything from the movie itself, to special features like bonus interviews, to studio and production company logo animations.

#### 2. Use [Inviska MKV Extract](https://www.inviska.com/mkvextract/) to extract everything else

According to its homepage, Inviska can extract video tracks, audio tracks, subtitle tracks, fonts, images, chapters, cuesheets, tags, cues and timestamps. In other words, Inviska can extract *everything* that a DVD can possibly contain.

However, unlike MakeMKV, Inviska can't use discs as a direct source, which is why you'll need an .MKV file created by MakeMKV for this step.

If you require any timestamp files or cues with Inviska, be sure to tick the checkboxes to the right before giving Inviska a source:

[image]

Then use `Add Files` to *import the .MKV file from step 1 that contains the main title* (i.e. the movie) as a source, add a destination directory for the tracks it contains to be extracted to, and select `Begin` to start extracting.

#### 3. (Optional) Use [MKVToolNix GUI](https://mkvtoolnix.download/) to remux extracted tracks into a video

If you're extracting the content from a DVD movie, then the odds are that at some point you're planning to re-mux the extracted tracks into a container like .MKV. This is easily accomplished with MKToolNix GUI, which is the GUI included as part of the [MKVToolNix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/) command-line suite.

Use the `Add Source Files` dialogue to import the tracks you extracted in previous steps, as well as any additional tracks you want to add into your new .MKV video, such as audio commentary or subtitle tracks downloaded from the web.

In the *Destination file* field, browse to the directory you want to save the re-muxed video to, give it a name, and select `Start Multiplexing`. Once MKVToolNix is done muxing, you'll end up with an .MKV container that contains all the tracks you imported and that can be played in virtually any media player.